# Getting related news by tags in Gatsby and GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I've been trying to get related news for articles in GraphQL.
Each article has 1 or more tags and based on those tags it needs to find up to 3 related articles with a new query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My query looks like this:

```
    strapiArticles(Slug: { eq: $slug }) {
        strapiId
        Title
        Date
        Content
        tags {
            tag
            slug
        }
        Image {
            publicURL
        }
    }
}
```

The tags bit looks like:

```
"tags": [
    {
      "tag": "Tag 1",
      "Slug": "tag-1"
    },
    {
      "tag": "Tag 2",
      "Slug": "tag-2"
    }
]
```

I've tried passing the tags in the context but Gatsby doesn't support arrays or object in the context. Like this:

```
createPage({
      path: `news/${edge.node.Slug}`,
      component: path.resolve("src/templates/news-post.js"),
      context: {
        tag: edge.node.tags,
        slug: edge.node.Slug,
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but Gatsby doesn't support arrays or object in the context.

That's not true. You can send an array of tags via context but you need to prepare your data first:

```
   let allTagsFromNode= edge.node.tags.map(tag=> tag.tag);
```

This should return all tag names (`tag`) for a specific new within a structure like `["Tag 1", "Tag 2"]`. Tweak it a little bit to get a simple one dimension array if needed.

```
createPage({
      path: `news/${edge.node.Slug}`,
      component: path.resolve("src/templates/news-post.js"),
      context: {
        allTagsFromNode,
        slug: edge.node.Slug,
      }
    })
```

*Note: because you are sending `allTagsFromNode` with the same key than the value, you can omit to send it by `allTagsFromNode: allTagsFromNode`*

Then, in your `news-post.js` template your query should look like:

```
export const newsData = graphql`
    query getNewsInformation ($slug: String!, $author: String, $allTagsFromNode: [String!]) {
        ## your news query
        relatedArticles: strapiArticles(
            filter: {
              tags: {elemMatch: {tag: {in: $allTagsFromNode}}}, 
              Slug: {ne: $slug}},
            limit: 3) {
            edges {
                node {
                  ## your node fields
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

Among tweaking the query to adapt it to your needs (since I don't know how your data structure looks like) and also adding the news query, what is important here is that you are sending your tags by `$allTagsFromNode`, declared as an array (it's called [list in GraphQL](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#lists-and-non-null)) of strings in:

```
$allTagsFromNode: [String!]
```

Now, you can query and filter from all your articles to get the related news:

```
relatedArticles: strapiArticles(
    filter: {
       tags: {elemMatch: {tag: {in: $allTagsFromNode}}}, 
       Slug: {ne: $slug}},
    limit: 3)
```

You are now filtering all tag names (`tag`) that are included in the `allTagsFromNode` list.

It's also important to notice that you don't want the same article to be included as related, that's why you are omitting it in `Slug: {ne: $slug}}` (using the `ne` filter).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! It has helped a lot and I feel like I'm very close. When I add the last query I do get the error "frontmatter is not defined in type". I've tried this: ```filter: { tags: { in: $allTagsFromNode }, Slug: { ne: $slug } }``` but that doesnt work either. I get the error that "Field 'in' is not defined by type"

Comment: The filter should look like: `filter: { tags: {tag: { in: $allTagsFromNode}}, slug: { ne: $slug }},`. Keep in mind that your tag name is called `tag` (inside `tags`) and is the field that matches the `allTagsFromNode`. In addition, now it's a matter of trials and errors in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` since the issue now is strictly related to your data structure.

Comment: Apparently my filter had to be: ```filter: {tags: {elemMatch: {tag: {in: $allTagsFromNode}}}, Slug: {ne: $slug}}```. This seems to work now, thanks!